# Remove All Directory Permissions

Tags: c#, .net, security, permissions

In C# (2.0) How do I remove all permissions to a directory, so I can limit the access.  I will be adding access back to a limited set of users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the classes in the [System.Security.AccessControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.aspx) namespace, and especially the [DirectorySecurity.RemoveAccessRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity.removeaccessrule.aspx) method.

Also, if you remove all the permissions then you won't be able to add any back afterwards :-)

Comment: I found this tool useful for checking my code worked ok. It shows you directory permissions set within the folder hierarchy. i.e. only where permissions are set, not inherited - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZLIioUl-5k

Answer (score 24):

*Disclaimer: I realise this has already been answered and accepted, and I really wanted to post this as a comment to the accepted answer, however the inability of being able to format comments has forced me to post this as an answer (which, technically, it is)....*

I was looking to do the same, and found your question. Stu's answer helped me come up with this solution. (Note that I'm only interested in removing explicit security).

```
private static DirectorySecurity RemoveExplicitSecurity(DirectorySecurity directorySecurity)
{
    AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = directorySecurity.GetAccessRules(true, false, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
    foreach (FileSystemAccessRule rule in rules)
        directorySecurity.RemoveAccessRule(rule);
    return directorySecurity;
}
```

And this is obviously used as follows:

```
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectorySecurity directorySecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
directorySecurity = RemoveExplicitSecurity(directorySecurity);
Directory.SetAccessControl(path, directorySecurity);
```

Comment: A perfectly valid additional answer!

Comment: Good solution but I think you should call it RemoveEXPLICIT not implicit, because you're removing the explicit rules here.

Comment: This should be marked the correct answer.  No disclaimer required.

Comment: Just wanted to add for future reference that this is a good standard solution but isn't enough to handle some permissions. The list of permissions returned by `GetAccessRules` are not always valid when passed back into `RemoveAccessRule`. This happens with the value for the level of access doesn't exist in the `FileSystemRights` enum, more info here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694834/encountering-a-filesystemrights-value-that-isnt-defined-in-enumeration/9694894#9694894

Answer (score 3):

Here is a great set of articles from CodeProject about Windows ACL programming:

[The Windows Access Control Model](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/accessctrl1.aspx)

[Part 3](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/accessctrl3.aspx) of the series shows .NET specific methods.

Answer (score 2):

System.IO.Directory.GetAccessControl() and then edit the returned FileSecurity object.

Comment: nearly the same ^^ I changed it now.