# How to set an access mask not representable with FileSystemRights (e.g. GENERIC_ALL) when using FileSystemSecurity/DirectorySecurity?

Tags: c#, .net, acl

[`FileSystemRights` is an enum with `Flags` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights) which is supposed to be used with [`DirectorySecurity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity) and [`FileSystemSecurity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemsecurity).

But when you create a `FileSystemAccessRule` via `new` you cannot pass an `int` for the access mask and what's worse, the existing public constructors will check the range of the passed value and raise an exception if the range is exceeded. Which means even a forcible cast such as `(FileSystemRights)0x10000000` (for `GENERIC_ALL`) will compile, but *always* fail.

So how can one use values for access mask which cannot be represented with `FileSystemRights` then, such as `GENERIC_ALL`?

---

**Rationale:**

1. ACEs with `GENERIC_ALL` as access mask occur in the wild
2. Since they occur in the wild, one should be able to create them. .NET makes it very hard, though.

The meaning of `GENERIC_ALL` can certainly be represented by `FileSystemRights.FullControl`, but in my case it was important to get an ACE with the access mask being set to `GENERIC_ALL`, not to something that's "effectively the same".

Answer (score 3):

My solution is based on the .NET framework 4.8 reference source an may not necessarily work for other versions. But since the solution involves a function also used when internally reading ACLs from the filesystem, I am optimistic that the interface won't simply be scrapped.

### TL;DR

```
var ace = dirsec.AccessRuleFactory(ident.User, 0x10000000,
    false, InheritanceFlags.None, PropagationFlags.None,
    AccessControlType.Allow)
    as FileSystemAccessRule; // <<<< IMPORTANT PART!
```

### Why does it fail?

The issue is that `FileSystemAccessRule` only has public constructors which will access the enum `FileSystemRights` and which will "validate" that by calling a private method named `AccessMaskFromRights()`. This means even though we can manage to build after forcibly passing `(FileSystemRights)0x10000000` to the constructors, we will always get the following exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The value '268435456' is not valid for this usage of the type FileSystemRights.
```

However, there is an `internal` constructor which takes `int accessMask` as second argument instead. This is how the constructor is declared:

```
internal FileSystemAccessRule(
    IdentityReference identity,
    int accessMask,
    bool isInherited,
    InheritanceFlags inheritanceFlags,
    PropagationFlags propagationFlags,
    AccessControlType type);
```

That's the one we need to access. But how?

**NB:** Unfortunately, even though we could create an `AccessRule` (from which `FileSystemAccessRule` is derived) the `AddAccessRule()` method of `FileSystemSecurity` and `DirectorySecurity` will not accept it, it only accepts `FileSystemAccessRule` as input.

### How to work around it?

After digging a bit further it turns out `FileSystemSecurity` does have a method named `AccessRuleFactory()` which internally also appears to be what's used whenever the `FileSystemAccessRule` instances get created from actual ACLs read from the file system.

Said method takes an `int accessMask` as well and - unsurprisingly - has access to the `internal` constructor mentioned above, which allows us to create a `FileSystemAccessRule` from an `int` as opposed to a `FileSystemRights` (which is simply missing our desired values).

```
public sealed override AccessRule AccessRuleFactory(
    IdentityReference identityReference,
    int accessMask,
    bool isInherited,
    InheritanceFlags inheritanceFlags,
    PropagationFlags propagationFlags,
    AccessControlType type);
```

So in essence what we need to do is to have an instance of `FileSystemSecurity` or `DirectorySecurity` which we can use to call `AccessRuleFactory()`.

```
DirectorySecurity dirsec = System.IO.Directory.GetAccessControl(
    System.IO.Path.GetTempPath());
using (WindowsIdentity ident = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
{
    // 0x10000000 == GENERIC_ALL
    var ace = dirsec.AccessRuleFactory(ident.User, 0x10000000,
        false, InheritanceFlags.None, PropagationFlags.None,
        AccessControlType.Allow)
        as FileSystemAccessRule; // <<<< IMPORTANT PART!
    dirsec.AddAccessRule(ace);
    // ... set dirsec on some directory ...
}
```

This creates a `FileSystemAccessRule` via the `DirectorySecurity.AccessRuleFactory()`, giving `GENERIC_ALL` access to the the user in whose context the current process is running.