# Unable to remove directory ACEs

Tags: c#, .net, acl

I am writing a class library using C# and .NET 4 that interacts with the filesystem on a shared server over the network. I am trying to adjust some permissions on a folder and I am perfectly capable to add ACEs, but I am struggling to remove them.

This is the code I have so far:

```
//get ACEs for the working folder.
DirectorySecurity disec = m_diWork.GetAccessControl();

//find out if the account we want to remove is inherited from a parent folder.
bool bIsAccountInherited = disec.GetAccessRules(false, true, typeof(NTAccount)).Cast<AuthorizationRule>().Any(ar => ar.IdentityReference.Value.Equals(act.Value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
if (bIsAccountInherited)
{
    //if so, remove inheritance of ACEs but preserve existing ones.
    disec.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, true);
}

//remove all access to this account.
disec.PurgeAccessRules(act);

//commit changes to working folder.
m_diWork.SetAccessControl(disec);
```

The variable `act` is of type NTAccount and refers to a domain user.

The code runs without exceptions or any apparent issues, and the permissions of the target folder are correctly changed to non-inheriting. However, no ACEs are removed at all.

I have tried several different combinations of method calls, also using `RemoveAccessRuleAll()`, to no avail. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445388/remove-all-directory-permissions

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer: Thanks, but I am well past that. I know the theory. :-)

Comment: @CesarGon Shouldn't disec.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, true); be disec.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, false);

Comment: @Brian: No, because I want to preserve (i.e. copy) whatever ACLs the folder is inheriting once I remove the inheritance flag.

Comment: We don't know nearly enough about *act*.  Watch out for a domain account and a local machine account having the same name.

Comment: @HansPassant: I have edited my question now to clarify this. Thanks.

Comment: Well, that's merely what I warned you about, what if it is not the domain user account?  You still didn't clarify how you got the *act* object.  If you use the simple NTAccount(name) constructor then you are liable to get the local account object.  Try NTAccount(domainName, accountName) instead.

Comment: @HansPassant: I use the `NTAccount(domainName, accountName)` constructor. I have checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lays in the fact that you are trying to remove inherited access rights what is not allowed. It happens because it is not enough to call *SetAccessRuleProtection(true, true)*. The changes will take effect only when you call *SetAccessControl* afterwards. In other words you cannot remove inheritance of access rights and modify them in the one shot. It must be done in 2 stages i.e.:

1. disec.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, true);
2. m_diWork.SetAccessControl(disec);
3. disec = m_diWork.GetAccessControl()
4. disec.PurgeAccessRules(act);
5. m_diWork.SetAccessControl(disec);

It is not obvious and it doesn't help that *PurgeAccessRules* doesn't inform about problems with removing access rights.

Comment: This worked, so many thanks. I wasted so much time and found the two-step process that you describe documented nowhere!